# How do I "sync" read/unread with Thunderbird and Hotmail

Tags: sync, thunderbird, email

After a fresh install of 12.04, I'm trying to use thunderbird for the first time, instead of a web browser (first of all, is it better and/or safer?). I noticed that, at least for hotmail, read emails aren't synchronized and remain unread in thunderbird if I read them in hotmail, and reciprocally.

Is there a way to change that ?

Comment: Did you configure Thunderbird to sync via POP or IMAP?

Comment: For common mail servers, such as gmail or hotmail, thunderbird does the internal work for you, so I don't really know. I think it's POP for hotmail.

Comment: I just tried searching but I'm surprised to see Hotmail may not support IMAP (which is two-way sync, what you want here). If this is correct, you may be stuck using a browser, or switching to a different service like GMail that supports this basic function. You can always forward from Hotmail to GMail so you don't miss any emails.

Comment: The 'mail' app on the iphone does that though (if a mail is read on the iphone, it appears as read in the browser, and reciprocally). So how does it work? Maybe it uses the 'exchange' protocol ? Could I not use that with thunderbird ?

Answer (score 1):

I should say that I am always quite surprise to see Ubuntu users complain about the fact that Thunderbird should supports closed standard... IMAP exists and is the solution. So if you want to be able to sync your mails status, you should just use another mail address.

Comment: This is what I have, and I can't change it just like that. Some apps do it well, so what can I do to make it work on thunderbird too? At least, a workaround please